# Will git revert overwrite any other changes made by other people?

Tags: git

Let's say I made some changes in my repository and later on found that I have to revert to a previous commit status, but at the same time some other people also made changes to the repository after my commit.

I want to revert the changes made by myself during this period of time, but not others who are working in the same repository. Is that possible in git?

More specifically, if in the past 3 days, I made 3 commits:

```
c1
c2
c3
```

During the same time period, another worker also made 2 commits:

```
c4
c5
```

I have 2 questions:

1. If I want to go back to the status before c1, is sufficient to revert it to c1? what about c2 and c3?
2. when I revert to c1, will c4 & c5 be affected as well?

Comment: Unclear because there is no such thing as "revert to" in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *revert* has a specific meaning in git. It means to create a commit that is the opposite of another commit.

Going back to a previous commit in history is called a *reset*.

About the revert, if now you have the sequence:

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
```

and you revert your first three commits (with `git revert`), better in reverse order, you end up with :

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
-c3
-c2
-c1
```

That should be more or less equivalent to just the work of `c4` and `c5` but keeping the whole story.

If you want to actually *remove* your commits you will have to rewrite the branch. The usual caveats of `rebase` and `push --force` apply (that is, not recommended if shared). There are a few ways to do that. The easiest would probably to do a `git rebase --interactive c1^` and remove the offending commits. Then a `push -f` and make sure that everybody in the team has synchronized properly.

Comment: So just revert to c1 is not enough. I have to revert c1, c2, and c3 individually?

Comment: @marlon: You do not revert **to** a commit, you revert a commit by creating an anti-commit, of sorts. But if you reset **to** a commit you will lose any history done after that

Comment: @malon: TL; DR; yes, I advice reverting all commits c3, c2, c1, in reverse order.

Comment: You can still restore those commits until they are garbage-collected.

Answer (score 1):

`git revert` simply reverses the patches in the specified commit(s).  If the reverse patch(es) can't be applied cleanly, git will give you an opportunity to resolve the conflicts, similar to when conflicts arise from a `merge` or `rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what you want to achieve because you use the term "revert" while describing a process called "branch reset" in Git.

If you revert one commit (say, C1) by saying `git revert C1`, other commits (C2, C3...) won't be affected because only that change will be "unapplied". Git will create an "anti-commit" for you (let's call it C6). However, if you want to reset your branch to C1 (`git reset C1`), you will effectively discard C2..C5. However, they will still exist until Git garbage-collects them sometime later (and you can restore them before its done by using `git reflog` to find the previous commits your branch pointed to).